# Toggle enabled&disabled all inputs in div when chceckbox clicked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, disabled-input

I am trying to remove the attribute disabled at each input when the chceckbox is clicked. I was able to turn these inputs on but I have a problem with switching them back off.

```
     <div class='single-service-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label><?php printf ("%s", $row["service_name"]); ?></label>
      <label>Ilość:</label><input type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?>" placeholder='ILOŚĆ' disabled/>
      <label>Cena netto:</label><input type="number" name="net_price" value="<?php echo $row["net_price"]; ?>" placeholder='CENA NETTO' disabled/>
    </div>


    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

    for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var div = this.parentNode;
        var x = div.childNodes;
        for(y=0; y < x.length; y++) {
          x[y].disabled = false;
        }
      }, false);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `x[y].disabled = !x[y].disabled;`?

Comment: it also disables my chceckbox when clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should substitude `x[y].disabled = false;` with

```js
if(x[y].type === "number") x[y].disabled = !x[y].disabled;
```

or if you want to disable all inputs, including your checkbox just use `x[y].disabled = !x[y].disabled;`.

Comment: now i try toggle 'name' to chcecked checkbox, because i nedd push all the choices to array in php